Problem with fullscreen API of javascript
I am doing a project that is somewhat clone of a powerpoint or canva, i am trying it go fullscreen using the js api but when ever the slide content changes it exits the fullscreen automatically.
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import "./form-template.css";
import { useRecoilState } from "recoil";
import { slides } from "../../recoil/atom/slideDataAtom";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
import Toolbar from "../editor/Toolbar";
import ResizeableContent from "../resizeable_content/ResizeableContent";
import ImageUpload from "../editor/ImageUpload";
import ContextMenu from "../context-menu/ContextMenu";

const Multipage = ({
  activeSlide,
  aiResponse,
  aiReset,
  copySlide,
  removeSlide,
  slideShow,
}) => {
  const [slide, setSlide] = useRecoilState(slides);
  const [clickedIndex, setClickedIndex] = useState(null);
  const editorRefs = useRef({});
  const [showContextMenu, setShowContextMenu] = useState(false);
  const [contextPosition, setContextPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [contextMenuItems, setContextMenuItems] = useState([]);
  const [elementContextMenu, setElementContextMenu] = useState(false);
  const slideContainerRef = useRef(null);

  const newTextboxData = {
    type: "TEXT",
    size: { width: "50%", height: "11%" },
    position: { x: 50, y: 100 },
    content: "",
  };

  const manipulateBackgroudImage = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    setSlide((prevData) => {
      const updatedSlide = prevData.map((slide, i) => {
        if (i === activeSlide) {
          return {
            ...slide,
            backgroundImage: data,
          };
        }
        return slide;
      });
      return updatedSlide;
    });
  };

  const manipulateSlideContentData = (contents, index) => {
    setSlide((prevData) => {
      const updatedSlide = prevData.map((slide, i) => {
        if (i === activeSlide) {
          const updatedData = slide.data.map((item, j) => {
            if (j === index) {
              return {
                ...item,
                content: contents,
              };
            }
            return item;
          });
          return {
            ...slide,
            data: updatedData,
          };
        }
        return slide;
      });
      return updatedSlide;
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const removeContextMenu = () => {
      setContextMenuItems([]);
      setShowContextMenu(false);
    };
    window.addEventListener("click", removeContextMenu);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("click", removeContextMenu);
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (aiResponse !== "") {
      manipulateSlideContentData(aiResponse, clickedIndex);
    }
    aiReset("");
  }, [aiResponse]);

  const deleteElement = useCallback(() => {
    setSlide((prevData) => {
      const updatedSlide = prevData.map((slide, i) => {
        if (i === activeSlide) {
          const updatedData = slide.data.filter(
            (item, j) => j !== clickedIndex
          );
          return {
            ...slide,
            data: updatedData,
          };
        }
        return slide;
      });
      return updatedSlide;
    });
    setElementContextMenu(false);
  }, [setSlide, activeSlide, clickedIndex]);

  const handleDeleteElement = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      if (event.key === "Delete") {
        deleteElement();
      }
    },
    [deleteElement]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleDeleteElement);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleDeleteElement);
    };
  }, [handleDeleteElement]);

  const handleAddTextbox = useCallback(() => {
    setSlide((prevData) => {
      const updatedSlide = prevData.map((slide, i) => {
        if (i === activeSlide) {
          const updatedData = [...slide.data, newTextboxData];
          return {
            ...slide,
            data: updatedData,
          };
        }
        return slide;
      });
      return updatedSlide;
    });
  }, [setSlide, activeSlide, newTextboxData]);

  const handleResizeStop = useCallback(
    (e, direction, ref, delta, position, type) => {
      const { width, height } = ref.style;
      const { x, y } = position;
      setSlide((prevData) => {
        const updatedSlide = prevData.map((slide, i) => {
          if (i === activeSlide) {
            const updatedData = slide.data.map((item, j) => {
              if (j === type) {
                return {
                  ...item,
                  size: { width, height },
                  position: { x, y },
                };
              }
              return item;
            });
            return {
              ...slide,
              data: updatedData,
            };
          }
          return slide;
        });
        return updatedSlide;
      });
    },
    [setSlide, activeSlide]
  );

  const handleDragStop = useCallback(
    (e, d, type) => {
      const { x, y } = d;
      setSlide((prevData) => {
        const updatedSlide = prevData.map((slide, i) => {
          if (i === activeSlide) {
            const updatedData = slide.data.map((item, j) => {
              if (j === type) {
                return {
                  ...item,
                  position: { x, y },
                };
              }
              return item;
            });
            return {
              ...slide,
              data: updatedData,
            };
          }
          return slide;
        });
        return updatedSlide;
      });
    },
    [setSlide, activeSlide]
  );

  const slideContentChangeHandler = useCallback(
    (e, index) => {
      const content = e;
      manipulateSlideContentData(content, index);
    },
    [setSlide, activeSlide]
  );

  const handleFocus = useCallback((editorId) => {
    console.log("editor id: ", editorId);
    setClickedIndex(editorId);
  });

  const handleAction = useCallback(
    (action, param) => {
      const editor = editorRefs.current[clickedIndex].getEditor();
      editor.focus();
      switch (action) {
        case "bold":
          editor.format("bold", !editor.getFormat().bold);
          break;
        case "italic":
          editor.format("italic", !editor.getFormat().italic);
          break;
        case "underline":
          editor.format("underline", !editor.getFormat().underline);
          break;

        case "align":
          editor.format("align", param);
          break;

        case "font":
          editor.format("font", param);
          break;
        case "size":
          editor.format("size", param);
          break;
      }
    },
    [clickedIndex]
  );

  const addImage = (imageUrl) => {
    console.log(imageUrl);
    const newImageBoxData = {
      type: "IMAGE",
      size: { width: "50%", height: "50%" },
      position: { x: 50, y: 100 },
      content: imageUrl,
    };

    setSlide((prevData) => {
      const updatedSlide = prevData.map((slide, i) => {
        if (i === activeSlide) {
          const updatedData = [...slide.data, newImageBoxData];
          return {
            ...slide,
            data: updatedData,
          };
        }
        return slide;
      });
      return updatedSlide;
    });
  };

  const handleGlobalContextMenu = (event) => {
    if (
      slide[activeSlide].data.length > 0 ||
      slide[activeSlide]?.backgroundImage
    ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
      const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
      if (
        slide[activeSlide]?.backgroundImage &&
        slide[activeSlide]?.data[clickedIndex]?.type !== "IMAGE"
      ) {
        setContextMenuItems([
          {
            lable: "Remove background image",
            onClick: removeBackgroundImage,
          },
        ]);
      } else {
        setContextMenuItems([
          {
            lable: "Set as background image",
            onClick: setBackgroundImage,
          },
        ]);
      }
      setContextPosition({
        x,
        y,
      });
      setShowContextMenu(true);
      console.log("context menu");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("contextmenu", handleGlobalContextMenu);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("contextmenu", handleGlobalContextMenu);
    };
  }, [handleGlobalContextMenu]);

  const setBackgroundImage = () => {
    setShowContextMenu(false);
    const src =
      slide[activeSlide]?.data[clickedIndex]?.type === "IMAGE"
        ? slide[activeSlide].data[clickedIndex].content
        : "";

    manipulateBackgroudImage(src);

    deleteElement();
    setElementContextMenu(false);
  };

  const removeBackgroundImage = () => {
    setShowContextMenu(false);
    manipulateBackgroudImage("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const enterFullscreen = () => {
      if (slideContainerRef.current) {
        if (slideContainerRef.current.requestFullscreen) {
          slideContainerRef.current.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (slideContainerRef.current.mozRequestFullScreen) {
          // Firefox
          slideContainerRef.current.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (slideContainerRef.current.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
          // Chrome, Safari and Opera
          slideContainerRef.current.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (slideContainerRef.current.msRequestFullscreen) {
          // IE/Edge
          slideContainerRef.current.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
      }
    };

    const exitFullscreen = () => {
      if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        // Firefox
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        // Chrome, Safari and Opera
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        // IE/Edge
        document.msExitFullscreen();
      }
    };

    if (slideShow) {
      enterFullscreen();
    } else {
      exitFullscreen();
    }
  }, [slideShow, activeSlide]); // Add activeSlide as a dependency

  return (
    <div
      className="row w-100  pb-3 mx-auto"
      onClick={() => {
        setShowContextMenu(false);
      }}
      role="outter-container"
    >
      {slide.length > 0 && (
        <div
          className={`box col-12 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-content-center ${
            slideShow ? "slideshow-mode" : ""
          }`}
          key={activeSlide}
        >
          {!slideShow && (
            <Toolbar onAction={handleAction} addTextbox={handleAddTextbox} />
          )}
          <ImageUpload onUpload={addImage} />
          <div
            className={`form-template p-5 w-100 ${
              slideShow ? "fullscreen" : ""
            }`}
            style={{
              backgroundImage: `url(${slide[activeSlide]?.backgroundImage})`,
              backgroundSize: "cover",
              backgroundPosition: "center",
              backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
              backgroundColor: slide[activeSlide]?.backgroundColor,
            }}
            id="slide"
            ref={slideContainerRef}
          >
            <div className="row w-100 h-100 position-relative" role="slide">
              {showContextMenu && (
                <ContextMenu
                  position={contextPosition}
                  onClose={() => setShowContextMenu(false)}
                  menuItems={contextMenuItems}
                  setBackgroundImage={setBackgroundImage}
                />
              )}
              {slide[activeSlide].data.length !== 0 ? (
                slide[activeSlide].data.map((item, i) => {
                  return (
                    <ResizeableContent
                      key={i}
                      editorId={i}
                      type={item.type}
                      initialSize={item.size}
                      initialPosition={item.position}
                      onResizeStop={(e, direction, ref, delta, position) => {
                        handleResizeStop(e, direction, ref, delta, position, i);
                      }}
                      onDragStop={(e, d) => {
                        handleDragStop(e, d, i);
                      }}
                      className="col-12 rnd-container position-absolute"
                      onFocus={handleFocus}
                      value={item.content}
                      onChange={(e) => slideContentChangeHandler(e, i)}
                      ref={(el) => (editorRefs.current[i] = el)}
                      slideShow={slideShow}
                    />
                  );
                })
              ) : (
                <></>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>

          {slide.length > 1 && (
            <div className="bottom-props">
              <span className="delete-icon-svg">
                <img
                  onClick={removeSlide}
                  className="img-responsive  cursor-pointer"
                  src="./../img/delete.svg"
                  alt=""
                />
              </span>
              <span className="copy-icon-svg pt-2">
                <img
                  onClick={copySlide}
                  className="img-responsive cursor-pointer"
                  src="./../img/copy.svg"
                  alt=""
                />
              </span>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Multipage;


The activeSlide inidcates which is the current slide and it's value changes in parent component.

Issue: When changing the slide content (e.g., adding or modifying text, images, or other elements), the application exits fullscreen mode automatically.
Behavior Observed: The fullscreen mode is triggered correctly, but any state change that re-renders the slide causes it to exit fullscreen.

Below is the code for parent component
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useRecoilState, useRecoilValue } from "recoil";
import { COLORS, VARIANT } from "./../constants";
import { Button } from "./../components/button/Button";
import EditIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Edit";
import Multipage from "../components/form_template/Multipage";
import { defaultContent, slides } from "../recoil/atom/slideDataAtom";
import axios from "axios";
import PromptComponent from "../components/prompt_box/PromptComponent";
import ColorPalette from "../components/color-palette/ColorPalette";
import DraggableSidePanel from "../components/draggable-side-panel/DraggableSidePanel";

const NewFormTemplate = () => {
  const [slide, insertSlide] = useRecoilState(slides);
  const defaultSlideContent = useRecoilValue(defaultContent);
  const [activeSlide, changeSlide] = useState(0);
  const [draftState, setDraftState] = useState(false);
  const [draftStateMessage, setDraftStateMessage] = useState("Save Draft");

  const [formName, setFormName] = useState("");
  const [newFormName, setNewFormName] = useState(formName);
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
  const [isEditMode, setIsEditMode] = useState(false);

  const [autoSaveToggle, setAutoSaveToggle] = useState(true);
  const [aiInputbox, setAiInputbox] = useState("");
  const [aiResponse, setAiResponse] = useState("");

  const [slideShow, setSlideShow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    addSlide();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleFullscreenChange = () => {
      if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
        setSlideShow(false);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", handleFullscreenChange);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("fullscreenchange", handleFullscreenChange);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleChangeSlide = (event) => {
      if (slideShow) {
        switch (event.key) {
          case "ArrowLeft":
            event.preventDefault();
            changeSlide((prevSlide) =>
              prevSlide > 0 ? prevSlide - 1 : prevSlide
            );
            break;
          case "ArrowRight":
            event.preventDefault();
            changeSlide((prevSlide) =>
              prevSlide < slide.length - 1 ? prevSlide + 1 : prevSlide
            );
            break;
          case "Escape":
            setSlideShow(false);
            break;
        }
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleChangeSlide);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleChangeSlide);
    };
  }, [slide.length, slideShow]);

  const addSlide = () => {
    setAutoSaveToggle((prevToggle) => !prevToggle);
    const items = slide;
    insertSlide([...items, defaultSlideContent]);
    changeSlide(items.length);
  };

  const changeFormNameHandler = (e) => {
    setNewFormName(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleFormNameSave = () => {
    setFormName(newFormName);
    setIsFocused(false);
    setIsEditMode(false);
    setAutoSaveToggle((prevToggle) => !prevToggle);
  };
  const removeSlide = (slideId) => {
    setAutoSaveToggle((prevToggle) => !prevToggle);
    const temp = [...slide];
    temp.splice(slideId, 1);
    if (slideId !== 0) {
      changeSlide(slideId - 1);
    } else {
      changeSlide(slideId);
    }
    insertSlide(temp);
  };
  const copySlide = (slideId) => {
    setAutoSaveToggle((prevToggle) => !prevToggle);
    const temp = [...slide];
    const newSlide = temp.slice();
    newSlide.splice(slideId, 0, { ...temp[slideId] });
    insertSlide(newSlide);
  };

  const slideChangeHandler = (slideId) => {
    changeSlide(slideId);
  };

  const slideInputHandler = (inputFiledId) => {
    const newArray = slides.map((item, i) => {
      if (activeSlide === i) {
        return {
          ...item,
          inputField: inputFiledId,
          options: ["", ""],
        };
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });
    insertSlide(newArray);
    if (inputFiledId === 8) {
      setDraftState(false);
      setDraftStateMessage("Save Draft");
    } else {
      setAutoSaveToggle((prevToggle) => !prevToggle);
    }
  };

  const handleFocus = () => {
    setIsFocused(true);
    setIsEditMode(true);
  };

  const handleEditIconClick = () => {
    setIsFocused(true);
    setIsEditMode(true);
  };

  const handleCancelClick = () => {
    if (formName !== "") {
      setIsFocused(false);
      setIsEditMode(false);
      setFormName(formName);
      setNewFormName(formName);
    }
  };

  const handleDragEnd = (result) => {
    if (!result.destination) {
      return;
    }
    const sourceIndex = result.source.index;
    const destinationIndex = result.destination.index;
    const reorderedSlides = Array.from(slide);
    const [removed] = reorderedSlides.splice(sourceIndex, 1);
    reorderedSlides.splice(destinationIndex, 0, removed);
    insertSlide(reorderedSlides);
  };

  const handleAiInputChange = (e) => {
    const input = e.target.value;
    setAiInputbox(input);
  };

  const sendToAiHandler = async () => {
    try {
      const inputItems = aiInputbox.split(",").map((item) => item.trim());
      const urlCount = inputItems.filter(
        (item) => item.startsWith("http://") || item.startsWith("https://")
      ).length;

      const isLinks =
        urlCount > 1 || (urlCount === 1 && inputItems.length === 1);

      const payload = isLinks ? inputItems : [aiInputbox];
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "https://thor-console.tarento.com/summarizer/gensim/summarize",
        {
          articles: payload,
          doc_link: "",
          word_count_per_article: "500",
          language: "en",
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      setAiResponse(data.payload.summary.answer.en);
      setAiInputbox("");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleReset = (res) => {
    console.log("inisde reset");
    setAiResponse(res);
  };

  const handleSlideshow = () => {
    setSlideShow(true);
  };

  const backgroundColorChangeHandler = (color) => {
    insertSlide((prevData) => {
      const updatedSlide = prevData.map((slide, i) => {
        if (i === activeSlide) {
          return {
            ...slide,
            backgroundColor: color,
          };
        }
        return slide;
      });
      return updatedSlide;
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container-fluid dashboard-header">
        {!slideShow && (
          <div className="fixed-top">
            <header className="create-form-header-2">
              <div className=" ">
                <div class="input-container">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className={
                      formName !== "" && !isFocused
                        ? "input-box-name"
                        : "input-box"
                    }
                    value={isEditMode ? newFormName : formName}
                    placeholder="Add content name here"
                    readonly={!isEditMode}
                    onFocus={handleFocus}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      changeFormNameHandler(e);
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              {!isEditMode && formName !== "" && !isFocused && (
                <div>
                  <EditIcon
                    className="edit-icon"
                    onClick={handleEditIconClick}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
              {isEditMode && isFocused && (
                <div className="d-flex">
                  <div className="d-flex align-items-center ms-3 me-3 text-decoration-underline font-weight-bold">
                    <span
                      className="cursor-pointer"
                      onClick={() => {
                        handleCancelClick();
                      }}
                      role="cancel-button"
                    >
                      cancel
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <Button
                    type="primary"
                    label="Save"
                    variant={VARIANT.ONE}
                    size="sm"
                    onClick={handleFormNameSave}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
              <div className="form-button">
                <div className=" me-3 form-preview-publish">
                  <Button
                    label="Preview"
                    variant={VARIANT.ONE}
                    size="md"
                    onClick={handleSlideshow}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </header>
          </div>
        )}
        <div
          className="row"
          style={{
            marginTop: "60px",
            flexWrap: "nowrap",
            position: "fixed",
            width: "100%",
          }}
        >
          <div className="col-md-2">
            <div className="row slides-container pb-3">
              <DraggableSidePanel
                slideChangeHandler={slideChangeHandler}
                handleDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
                slide={slide}
                activeSlide={activeSlide}
              />

              <div className="row px-4 ms-1">
                <Button
                  type="secondary"
                  variant="secondary"
                  size="lg"
                  label="Add Slide"
                  onClick={addSlide}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          {/* slide view area starts here */}

          <div className="col-md-8 d-flex align-content-center template-view ">
            <Multipage
              activeSlide={activeSlide}
              aiResponse={aiResponse}
              aiReset={handleReset}
              copySlide={() => copySlide(activeSlide)}
              removeSlide={() => removeSlide(activeSlide)}
              slideShow={slideShow}
            />
          </div>

          {/* Edit your content-creator starts here */}
          <div className="col-md-2 right-sidebar">
            {/* Prompt box */}

            <PromptComponent
              aiInputbox={aiInputbox}
              handleAiInputChange={handleAiInputChange}
            />
            <div className="mt-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
              <Button
                label="Search"
                variant={VARIANT.ONE}
                size="md"
                onClick={sendToAiHandler}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="row  mt-4">
              <div className="col-12">
                <p className="section-heading">Background Colors</p>
              </div>
              <div className="row mb-1 colors-container">
                {slide.length > 0 && (
                  <ColorPalette
                    backgroundColorChange={backgroundColorChangeHandler}
                  />
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default NewFormTemplate;

Below is the atom
const slides = atom({
  key: "slides",
  default: [],
});

const defaultContent = atom({
  key: "defaultContent",
  default: {
    data: [
      {
        type: "TEXT",
        size: { width: "100%", height: "11%" },
        position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        content: "",
      },
      {
        type: "TEXT",
        size: { width: "100%", height: "75%" },
        position: { x: 0, y: 100 },
        content: "",
      },
    ],
  },
});


Have you considered using an <iframe> to contain your content?

Will ifame solve the issue as the the problem is with changing the slide array value

Can't say much without the code for the parent component that manages the state and logic for activeSlide and slideShow.

Code for parent component uploaded

The benefit is that you can reload the <iframe> without affecting the outer page, so the browser doesn't see a reload.
